# Выводить дату на английском

Tags: java, groovy

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
```

Выводит четверг, а надо на английском.

Comment: Вывод зависит от локальных настроек окружения пользователя. Если вы хотите, можете задать принудительно другие настройки. Используйте для этого конструктор с передачей имени региональных стандартов: new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", Locale.ENGLISH);

Comment: @AlexKrass перенесите ваш комментарий в ответ)

Comment: @AntonSorokin ну.... в ответах хорошо бы все рассписывать, а в комментариях можно двумя предложениями отделаться и предоставить написание ответа кому-то еще. Но если никто не хочет расписать, то ладно, перенесу в ответ.

Comment: @AlexKrass возможно, кто нибудь хочет. Если вы мне не ответили, то я бы сам написал бы ответ. Но это выглядело бы так, как будто я своровал ваш комментарий, поэтому я предварительно спросил, не хотите ли вы перенести все в ответ

Comment: @AntonSorokin, ох уж эта солидарность) Обычно, если комментарий несет полноценный ответ без предположений, то человеку некогда или лень расписывать полноценный ответ. Сразу бы написали дополнительно "... ну или я оставлю ответ". С радостью отдал бы вам это право.

Answer (score 5):

Поскольку в разных частях света используются разные представления информации и стандарты, то на компьютерах пользователей как правила есть файлы, которые за них отвечают. Эти параметры и настройки часто используются в программах и называются `locale` ("локаль" или на русском "региональные настройки"). Они задают язык, страну, часовой пояс, наборы символов, направление текста и другие параметры.

Класс `SimpleDateFormat` как раз служит примером, как эти региональные настроки используются и для разных компьютеров вы можете получать различные результаты, которые будут удобны для пользователя. Обычно он использует локаль, которая по умолчанию заданна в операционной системе: `Locale.getDefault()`.

Если вы хотите, можете задать принудительно другие настройки. Используйте для этого конструктор с передачей имени региональных стандартов:

`new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", Locale.ENGLISH);`.